# Is there a way to set C# readonly auto-implemented Propeties through reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, field, readonly

The title says all: 
Is there a way to set C# readonly auto-implemented Propeties through reflection?

```
typeof(Change)
    .GetProperty("ChangeType", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    .SetValue(myChange, change.ChangeType.Transform(),null);
```

This line gives me an error : **System.ArgumentException - {"Property set method not found."}**. The thing is I can't use **GetField** because there are no fields.

Before you ask, I'm doing this because I need to "complement" an already finished library and I have no access to its code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, so there is something that you are not telling us. Are you sure that it's an auto-implemented property? An explanation consistent with what you are seeing is that the property is not auto-implemented and does not have a setter.

That is,

```
public class Foo { public int Bar { get; set; } }

typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar").SetValue(foo, 42);
```

will succeed but

```
public class Foo { public int Bar { get { return 42; } } }

typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar").SetValue(foo, 42);
```

will not and it will produce the exception with the message that you are seeing.

Comment: Oh. Yeah, I guess this is it. The Property doesn't have a setter... which doesn't make a lot of sense since I have no idea what its 'get' is actually getting. The class has no fields, but it does have these 3 properties without setters (that's why I assumed they were auto-implemented). I guess the only way to change it would be... finding what the getter does, and changing what I need. Any clue how could I do that ?

Comment: @Jason - brainfart, comment deleted after I had a chance to actually think about it.

Comment: @Conrad Clark: Use reflector to peer into the getter.

Comment: Are you saying they may not be auto-implemented?  A tool like Reflector should tell you what's going on in the code behind the getter.

Comment: @James B: Given the issue that the OP is seeing, they are definitely not auto-implemented.

Comment: @tvanfosson: No problem, deleting my reply to your initial comment.

Comment: @Tim Robinson/Jason Thanks, Reflector is awesome =)

Answer (score 1):

the obvious conclusion would be that `Change.ChangeType` does not have public instance setter.

Comment: Not quite. If it is an auto-implemented public property with a private setter the above will still succeed showing that it can not have a public instance setter and still work.